# Firestore where clause for inequality

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to retrieve a value from firestore for in-equality, I know firestore does not support `!=` operator.
We have use this  clause `where("age", "<", "30").where("age", ">" 30)`
I want to know how i can use this clause if i want to retrieve the value of string

```
document.where('courseName','<','MBA').where('courseName','>','MBA').get().then(function(querySnapshot){
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
             var result3 ="Others"
            var result = querySnapshot.size
})
})
```

It is showing the value as null

Comment: Your current query returns documents for which `courseName` is both smaller than `"MBA"` and bigger than `"MBA"`, which is by definition not true for any documents. Firestore doesn't support inequality queries. See the question I linked for more answers.

Comment: So how i can get a document where ```courseName``` is not ```MBA```. Is there any way?

Comment: You'll need to fire two queries and then combine them client-side.